# Is there any life from Earth that can live on Mars?

Tags: mars, life, earth, terraforming

Does Mars have any environment in which a plant, virus or otherwise would be  capable of living on Mars without an artificial environment? Is there anything that can live below the Armstrong Limit on Mars?

Comment: Not duplicates, but there are some interesting answers and comments to [Are not crash landings on Mars violating the Planetary Protection rules?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26800/12102) and also [Why is Curiosity not heading for Peace Vallis?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26273/12102) that you might find worth perusing!

Comment: However, can you find a way to make your question further different from [What existing life on Earth is best suited for the Martian environment?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8963/12102) than it is? You might add a link to this question, then explain that answers there don't really address all of Mars's conditions at once.

Comment: _What if everything was provided…..but the atmospheric **pressure** ?_ Do you mean the **composition** of the "breathing" air for the living organism could be different from the composition of the atmosphere of Mars ?

Comment: Let the cyanobacteria be our scouts, like they were on Earth, to find a way of life.

Comment: You mean besides humans right? We can make our own environment like no creature that ever was.

Comment: @Joshua we could not live on Mars without a pressure suit.

Comment: @Muze, yes, but we make pressure suits!

Comment: As uhoh pointed out, seems like pretty much a duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8963/what-existing-life-on-earth-is-best-suited-for-the-martian-environment.

Comment: @uhoh thanks for the links. I wish there was a way to like your comment where you can see it was me!

Comment: I think the important clarifications are whether you talk about *surviving* for some time or *living* for several generations, also whether you talk about Martian surface (where probably no earth organism can live) or in general, including deep underground (where some optimism may exist but probably not enough data collected yet to be sure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The German Aerospace Center found that lichens and a Cyanobacteria could survive on the surface of mars for at least a month after subjecting them to mars like conditions.

Article on the subject: http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/20120515-earth-life-survive-mars.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check out all of SE. You are the only one who made an attempt to answer this question. Here is 50 bonus reputation points to help you get started.